# `RunWorkerCompleted` not being always being fired

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I'm using several external services when items in my application are completed. Each service I must contact gets it's own `BackgroundWorker` to perform its task. I keep track of how many workers completed their work to determine if there were any errors. The issue I'm running into is that `RunWorkerCompleted` doesn't always get fired.

Here is what I have:

```
var exceptionsCaught = new List<Exception>();
var completedCount = 0;

foreach(var notificationToSend in NotificationQueue)
{
    var backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
    backgroundWorker.DoWork += (sender, b) => notificationToSend();
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerCompleted += (sender, args) =>
                                               {
                                                   Console.WriteLine("Done.");
                                                    if(args.Error != null)
                                                    {
                                                        exceptionsCaught.Add(args.Error);
                                                        Console.WriteLine("Error! {0}", args.Error.Message);
                                                    }
                                                   completedCount++;
                                               };
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

var exceptionCheckerWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
exceptionCheckerWorker.DoWork += (sender, b) =>
                 {
                     while (true)
                     {
                         if (completedCount != NotificationQueue.Count) continue;
                         if (exceptionsCaught.Any())
                         {
                             var notificationExceptionMessage =
                                 new NotificationExceptionsMessage(exceptionsCaught,
                                                                   _notificationGeneratedPath);
                             _eventAggregator.Publish(notificationExceptionMessage);

                             break;
                         }

                         break;
                     }
                 };
exceptionCheckerWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
```

What am I missing?

When it fails to get called I see `The thread 0x2e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).` in my console.

I have changed the way I increment my count by using `Interlocked` but that hasn't changed anything. I know the event isn't being called because I have a breakpoint set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure that the `RunWorkerCompleted` event is not raised? The most likely cause is that you're not incrementing the `completedCount` field properly. Try using the [Interlocked methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
Interlocked.Increment(ref completedCount);
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure because I have a breakpoint set in there. Also, when it fails to get called I see `The thread 0x2e0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).` in my console.

Answer (score 2):

You have race condition when incrementing completedCount.  You should use Interlocked.Increment

Answer (score 1):

I don't know but you are writing a multi-threaded procedure that shears global data without a single lock, something surly is going wrong.